# App stops when a checklist is checked

Tags: android

When a checklist is checked the app stops and there is a logcat error.
I'm not sure why but I'll include code below and if you need me to include more, feel free to ask.

```
03-14 06:42:09.980 29887-29887/xyz.ashraf.whoisdelasalle E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: xyz.ashraf.whoisdelasalle, PID: 29887
                                                                           java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onCheckboxClicked(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.widget.CheckBox with id 'respect'
                                                                               at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(View.java:4485)
                                                                               at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4449)
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
                                                                               at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:122)
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

^^log cat error^^

```
package xyz.ashraf.whoisdelasalle;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.who);
        Button today = (Button) findViewById(R.id.today);
        Button sallian = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sallian);
        Button how = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toBe);
        Button moreInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.info);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pop.class));
            }
        });

        today.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pop_today.class));
            }
        });
        sallian.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pop_sallian.class));
            }
        });
        how.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pop_how.class));
            }
        });
        moreInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pop_info.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

^^Main Activity^^

```
package xyz.ashraf.whoisdelasalle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

/**
 * Created by Ashraf on 1/27/2016.
 */
public class Pop_sallian extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.popwindow_sallian);

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

        int width = dm.widthPixels;
        int height = dm.heightPixels;

        getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*.8),(int)(height*.6));

        Button checkButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.check);
        checkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Pop_sallian.this, check_Button.class));
            }
        });
        Button okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okButton_sallian);
        okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

^^Code where the check button that calls checkbutton.java is ^^

```
package xyz.ashraf.whoisdelasalle;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;

/**
 * Created by Ashraf on 3/2/2016.
 */
public class check_Button extends Pop_sallian {
    // Connects The variable to an xml id


    TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);

    //sets the variable to 0
    int score = 0;

    public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.concern:
                if (checked) {
                    score += 1;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.faith:
                if (checked) {
                    score += 1;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.respect:
                if (checked) {
                    score += 1;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.education:
                if (checked) {
                    score += 1;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.community:
                if (checked) {
                    score += 1;
                }
                break;
        }

        // adds the variables together to form a score

        if (score == 0) {
            output.setText("Come on! Get involved, your la sallian community needs you.");
        } else if (score == 1) {
            output.setText("Good start, keep going!");
        } else if (score == 2) {
            output.setText("Room to improve but doing good!");
        } else if (score == 3) {
            output.setText("Very good, others look up to you!");
        } else if (score == 4) {
            output.setText("Wow, you really are an inspiration");
        } else if (score == 5) {
            output.setText("Excellent! You're a leader in your la sallian community");
        } else {
            output.setText("Unknown");
        }
        // changes the output text based on score value
    }
}
```

^^Code that checks how many checklist have been checked and adds a value to it.^^

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Are you a Sallian?"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Do you meet the following prerequisites, if you do you may be a Sallian"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Are you concerened for the poor and Social Justice?"
        android:id="@+id/concern"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Do you have faith in the presence of God?"
        android:id="@+id/faith"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/concern"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Do you have Respect for all people?"
        android:id="@+id/respect"
        android:layout_below="@+id/faith"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Do you value education?"
        android:id="@+id/education"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/respect"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Are you inclusive in your community?"
        android:id="@+id/community"
        android:layout_below="@+id/education"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ok"
        android:id="@+id/okButton_sallian"
        android:layout_below="@+id/community"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="#FAFAFA"
        android:textColor="#00E676"
        android:elevation="2dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Check"
        android:id="@+id/check"
        android:textColor="#00E676"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:background="#FAFAFA"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/okButton_sallian"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/output"
        android:textColor="#1eff00"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/community"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/check"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />
</RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

^^XML^^

Please include code examples as a part of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you do not have any method in your activity with this name onCheckboxClicked.

as you have added onClick method in xml see below

```
   <CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Are you concerened for the poor and Social Justice?"
    android:id="@+id/concern"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>
```

> android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"

check out for all check boxes.

you need to add a method in your activty like this

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View v){
// do what ever you want.
}
```

> but for check box there is no need to add such methods. you just need to add onCheckChangedListener

in you activity and check the status of the your check box.

add this in your activity onCreate

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox ) findViewById(R.id.concern);

checkBox .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        // your check box is checked now. do what ever you wnat
                    } else {
                        // you check box is uncheckd now do what ever you want.
                    }
                }
            });
```

do the same for all check boxes.

if want want to change the check box status on any button click

then do the following things.

> get all the checkbox view in you activity. like i did for concern cehck Box

and inside the button click do this

```
checkbox.setchecked(true)
```

or

```
checkbox.setchecked(false)
```

i hope you understand now what i just said.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but where do I put it in my code?

Comment: what you want to put? checkchanged listener or onCheckboxClicked method?

Comment: if you want to add listener then you can add this inside your onCreate. and if you want to add method add it any where outside the onCreate scope.

Comment: I honestly don't know the difference. I want it to check if anything has changed or been clicked since the activity launched.

Comment: you want to check it on what basis? please explain so i can tell further.

Comment: The point of my code is to have users check the checklists pertaining to them than add the number of Checklists checked and than get an output.

Comment: I need either a checkchanged listener or an onCheckboxClicked method because without it the value is always 0.

Comment: actually i am not getting what you want.. i have updated the code please check  may that helps you. if you need any help let me know.

Comment: would it help if I gave you the full project file through github

Comment: brother actually i don't know the purpose of your project. if you can tell the exact problem i can help you. if can't explain then i wont be able to help much

Comment: The problem is I want to check if checklists are checked. If they are I add 1 to the int score. At the start the problem was I would always get the score of 0. I was told that this was because It checked the checklists upon creation. I've tried multiple ways to have it checked after the checkbutton is checked but I have come across many problems.

Answer (score 0):

In the xml file you have declared for checkboxes:

```
android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
```

That means that in your activity you need to declare method:

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View view){}
```

Comment: I have it declared in check_Button

Comment: It must be in activity which uses this layout resource.